# Loop comparing cells with array values vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a loop comparing all the values from the column A with all the values from MyArray. If cell value is the same as some value from the array, I would like to copy that cell to another corresponding sheet (All sheets are named as elements in the array).

```
Sub sheets()

    Dim MyArray As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim i As Integer

    FinalRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ws

'Part that creates my Array without duplicates


.Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
MyArray = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))

End With

'I copy column A from another sheet in order to restore values erased with .removeduplicates
'I've tried to remove duplicates from the Array itself but I kept getting errors so I've decided to go with this workaround
ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(2, 1)


For Each element In MyArray
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = element
Next element

' Below part works well but only for the number of rows equal to number of elements in the array ~15

For i = 2 To FinalRow
    For Each element In MyArray

        If element = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then

        ws.Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets(element).Cells(i, 1)

        End If

  Next element

Next i

ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Everything seems to work fine but only for the number of rows equal to number of elements in the array.
I think that there is something wrong with the logic in the loop but I can't see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? Your loop runs to FinalRow but you subsequently change the values in column A so presumably is not up to date. You can use Match to avoid the inner loop.

```
Sub sheets()

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim element As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim v As Variant

With ws
    .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    MyArray = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(2, 1)

For Each element In MyArray
    wb.sheets.Add(After:=wb.sheets(wb.sheets.Count)).Name = element
Next element

For Each r In ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    v = Application.Match(r, MyArray, 0)
    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        r.Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets(CStr(MyArray(v,1))).Cells(r.Row, 1)
    End If
Next r

ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Also with a dictionary

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteToSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim MyArray As Variant, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long, dict As Object, rng As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ws
        MyArray = Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
        For i = LBound(MyArray, 1) To UBound(MyArray, 1)
            If Not dict.exists(MyArray(i, 1)) Then
                dict.Add MyArray(i, 1), 1
                On Error Resume Next 'in case already exists
                wb.sheets.Add(After:=wb.sheets(wb.sheets.Count)).Name = MyArray(i, 1)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    With ws2
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
            If dict.exists(rng.Value) Then
                rng.Copy wb.Worksheets(rng.Value).Range("A" & GetNextRow(wb.Worksheets(rng.Value), 1))
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetNextRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetNextRow = IIf(.Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row = 1, 1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to analyze this code as I don't have experience with dictionaries but I will definitely use it in the future

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Dictionary` object

```
Sub sheetss()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object

    With ThisWorkbook ' reference wanted workbook
        Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With .Worksheets(1) ' reference referenced workbook relevant worksheet
            For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)) ' loop through referenced worksheet column A cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
                dict1(cell.Value) = 1 'store unique values from looped cells into dictionary keys
            Next
        End With

        Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With .Worksheets("Sheet2") ' reference referenced workbook relevant worksheet
            For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)) ' loop through referenced worksheet column A cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
                dict2(cell.Value) = dict1.exists(cell.Value) 'store unique values from looped cells into dictionary keys and its presence in first worksheet column A cells into corresponding item
            Next
        End With

        Dim key As Variant
        For Each key In dict2.keys ' loop through 2nd worksheet column A unique values
            If dict2(key) Then ' if it was in 1st worksheet column A cells also
                .sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.sheets(ThisWorkbook.sheets.Count)).Name = key ' create corresponding worksheet
                .sheets(key).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = key ' copy its value into cell B1 of newly created worksheet
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have experience with dictionaries but your comments are really helpful for me to understand how they work.

Comment: Let me know what will be your final choice